# Passing a structure in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

When I pass a `struct` pointer to a function, I want the changes made to the pointer to remain after the function ends. I do not know what I have done wrong.

```
void webSocketHandler(struct libwebsocket_context* context)
{    
    /* some code */
    context = libwebsocket_create_context(&info);
}

sint32 s32_WSER_Init(sint32* configDataPoolIndexes, struct libwebsocket_context* context)
{
   /* some code */
  webSocketHandler(configDataPoolIndexes, context);
}
```

The problem is that `context` is not `NULL` inside `webSocketHandler` after creating it, but if I try to use it inside `s32_WSER_Init` after calling the handler, I get `NULL`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to modify *pointer* to struct, you must pass *pointer to pointer* to struct:

```
void webSocketHandler(struct libwebsocket_context** context)
{    
    /* some code */
    /* info parameter missing above? */
    *context = libwebsocket_create_context(&info);
}


sint32 s32_WSER_Init(sint32* configDataPoolIndexes, struct libwebsocket_context* context)
{
   /* some code */
  webSocketHandler(configDataPoolIndexes, &context);
}
```

Your original code will modify the value of the `context` parameter, which is basically a local variable in the function. C has no actual references, it has passing pointer by value, which then allows modifying the original through the pointer. If original is pointer, and you want to modify it, you need to pointer to pointer.

Comment: Thanks. I passed normal pointers like this so i thought that it would be the same for structures.

Comment: @ModasserRahman In C, you can handle structures like any values, for example ints. It surprisingly high level feature in a language like C, really. You can for example pass and return and assign (known and fixed length) arrays by value by wrapping them in a struct.

Comment: thnx alot @hyde. I have another question related to this. How do i use `b->state` in the function
`function(struct a** b){ (*b)->state;}`
I have tried it in this form but `(*b)->state` does not work

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to pass the pointer *by reference*. Unfortunately C does not have that, but it can be *emulated* using pointers:

```
void webSocketHandler(struct libwebsocket_context** context)
{
    ...
    *context = ...;
    ...
}

void some_other_function(void)
{
    struct libwebsocket_context* context = NULL;
    ...
    webSocketHandler(&context);
    ...
}
```